# How can I manually edit the search options in a facet block?

Tags: search

I have a facet for a field, the values of which are:

(FACETAPI DEFAULT)

- *yes* (db: **y**)
- *no* (db: **n**)
- *maybe* (db: **m**)

By default, the facet shows all three of these options.  However, I only want to show *yes* or *no* to the user, and I want to include the value of *maybe* in both:

(WHAT I WANT)

- *yes* (db: **y** or **m**)
- *no* (db: (**n** or **m**)

**What I have tried**

I know I could try to do an OR search with the facet and rewrite my links to search both, but I don't want to give users the option to search just "maybe"; I only want two options, not three.

It would be great if there was a stable version of the [Apachesolr Facet Builder](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_facetbuilder) for D7.  One can dream...

I am using the [Facet API Bonus](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_bonus) module but this allows me to "Rewrite items" or "Exclude items," not combine three items into two as I described above.

I read this [wunderkraut article on extending Facet API](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/get-wild-with-facets-extending-facet-api/2012-01-17) but it covers adding sorts, plugins, widgets, dependencies, and the like-- not the facets themselves.

I also looked at this [wunderkraut article](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/build-advanced-content-listings-with-apache-solr-search-api-facet-api/2012-04-20), which suggests I should use something like `hook_facetapi_facet_info_alter()`, but I don't know how to edit the field values to combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to implement this by creating a new facet instead of editing an existing one.  [This article](http://ygerasimov.com/add-custom-field-search-api-apachesolr-index) describes the process.

The basic code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_property_info_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['user']['properties']['agg_gender'] = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => t('Search API Agg Gender'),
    'sanitized' => TRUE,
    'getter callback' => 'MYMODULE_search_agg_gender_getter_callback',
  );
}

/**
 * Getter callback for agg gender property.
 */
function MYMODULE_search_agg_gender_getter_callback($item) {
  // Need to load the user object to get fields
  $account = user_load($item->uid);
  switch ($account->field_gender['und'][0]['value']) {
    case 'F':
      return 'f';
      break;
    case 'M':
      return 'm';
      break;
    case 'O':
      return 'fm';
      break;
  }
}
```